# Parameters with infix operator name?

Tags: syntax, idris, infix-notation

In Haskell, we can use an infix operator as a parameter name, e.g.:

```
f :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
f (|+|) = 3 |+| 4
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Idris 2? I tried the following:

```
f : (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
f (|+|) = 3 |+| 4
```

But it fails with:

> ```
>  Unknown operator '|+|'
>  
>  slice:2:11--2:18
>   1 | f : (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
>   2 | f (|+|) = 3 |+| 5
>                 ^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: do you need to declare it `infix` first?